# Least CPU intense call in python to use in while loop

Tags: python, wiringpi

I'm currently using wiringpi to control the GPIO ports of a mcp23017 expansion board for my Raspberry Pi.
One of the GPIOs should be used as an input and wait for a INT_EDGE_FALLING event.
Wiringpi itself supports an interrupt mode but for whatever reason supports this only up to pin number 63 - mine is pin 70.

So I'm stuck with somthing like this:

```
wiringpi.pinMode(70,0)
wiringpi.pullUpDnControl(70,2)
while wiringpi.digitalRead(70) == 1:
    print "not pressed"
```

This loop causes a CPU usage of about 6% - is there any way to reduce this?
Which is the least cpu intense command to use within the while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [pass](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement) statement to do nothing.

```
while wiringpi.digitalRead(70) == 1:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you - cpu usage is about 3% now